# how to merge n files using mapreduce code?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have n number of files and i have to merge those  files (using map reduce code only)
for example i am taking 2 sample files.

> **file 1.txt**
>
> opened files is  file 1.txt this is the data in file1.txt

.

> **file 2.txt**
>
> opened files is  file 2.txt this is the data in file2.txt

I need to merge these two files and the expected output to be a part_0001 file of reducer expecting to be combination of both

> opened files is  file 1.txt this is the data in file1.txt
>
> opened files is  file 2.txt this is the data in file2.txt

i know that this can be easily achieved using hadoop -getmerge but i need a simple mapreduce job to work for me.

**can anyone help me with the logic that i have to follow for the mapper and the reducer (what has to be the key and values that has to be set in mapper and reducer)??**

Comment: you can also use the `hadoop dfs -cat` shell command

Comment: You can simply achieve this using hive. Just load these files in a hive table and create a second file using create table table2 as select * from table 1; This will work well without any additional settings if the total size of files are less than split size.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in multiple ways.

**1) Using a hive query**

Just load these files in a hive table and create a second file using create table table2 as select * from table 1; This will work well without any additional settings if the total size of files are less than split size.
If the file sizes are larger, set the following properties and execute the query.
*set mapreduce.reduce.tasks = 1;*
*set hive.exec.reducers.max = 1;*

**2) Using a mapreduce program**

In the mapper class, set the key as 1 and value as the text. This will ensure that all the data will go to a single reducer. Then in the reducer class, write the text alone and omit the key.